# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

Please why am I having this error

```
Error creating bean with name 'contactController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.viralpatel.contact.service.ContactService net.viralpatel.contact.controller.ContactController.contactService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.viralpatel.contact.dao.ContactDAO net.viralpatel.contact.service.ContactServiceImpl.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory net.viralpatel.contact.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
```

This is my contact service class

```
@Service
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {

    @Autowired
    private ContactDAO contactDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        contactDAO.addContact(contact);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Contact> listContact() {

        return contactDAO.listContact();
```

This is a decription of my header in pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Spring3HibernateMaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring3HibernateMaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description></description>
  <name>SpringHibernateMvc Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
```

This is the point I defined the properties of my pom.xml

```
<properties>
  <org.springframework-version>
  4.0.0.RELEASE
  </org.springframework-version>
  <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
  <org.aspectj-version>1.8.0</org.aspectj-version>
  <org.slf4j-version>1.7.12</org.slf4j-version>
  </properties>
```

These are my dependency files

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Addition of more dependencies

```
<!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency> 

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This is my spring-servlet.xml file and configuration

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.contact" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Please kindly assist!

Comment: It is a libraries incompatibility problem.  Please, add a Hibernate version, `pom.xml` or  a list of jars,  a web-cotainer (`Tomcat`) or an application server,  spring configuration files.

Comment: Those has been done.

Comment: @JnG he meant here, so we can check them.

Comment: I have pom.xml, I have web container and spring configuration. Source co the tutorial http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/

Comment: Dont get you please @dambros

Comment: what version of hibernate you are using. Please add your servlet.xml

Comment: Add your configuration files here on SO so we can check the content @JnG

Comment: I have done the edits. Many thanks

Comment: Is there any more information, you demand from me.

Comment: Please, add `spring-servlet.xml` and specify where you deploy your project.

Comment: You have configured hibernate3 but you have a dependency on hibernate5. Next to that spring 4.0 doesn't have official support for hibenate5.1... You should at least use the hibernate5 packages instead of the hibernate3 packages.

Comment: Yeah. that has been rectified

Comment: nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml] >>>> this is the error I am having now

Comment: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml];

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean on this file spring-servlet.xml

Answer (score 12):

In your spring-servlet.xml change the mapping

from

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

to

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

and the following as well

from

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
```

to

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
```

because you are using hibernate5.

Add  the spring-orm mapping as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am now getting this error>>>> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Comment: nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]

Comment: Could not autowire field: private net.viralpatel.contact.service.ContactService net.viralpatel.contact.controller.ContactController.contactService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Comment: add spring-orm dependency in your pom.xml

Comment: Do you mean something like this

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

Comment: Please I have added it

Comment: The error still re-occurs. Do I upgrade the version of my spring-orm to 5.xxx to match the value version of the hibernate

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean on this file spring-servlet.xml

Comment: I am upvoting for your support so far.

Comment: This is my spring version  <org.springframework-version>
  4.0.0.RELEASE
  </org.springframework-version>

Comment: try one more thing, change your spring version to 4.2.2 and hibernate to 5.0.2.Final

Comment: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor

Comment: please how can add aopalliance as a dependency in my pom.xml

Answer (score -4):

Please add the `commons-pool.jar` in the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder...
[Download the commons-pool.jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/download_pool.cgi)

Then restart the application...

Comment: I am using maven dependencies. So all the jars are added in my pom.xml

Comment: since this is a maven project it will get the jars.