# Why this Error Message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition is shown?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Problem:
I found the following error shown below:

Solution:
I have pasted the following dependencies in the pom.xml.
Got the jar file in maven dependency also but I am still getting the following error.

Below are the screenshot for reference

> Can anyone guide me how to correct this?

---

[image: pom.xml]
Below is the screenhot of maven depedencies present
[image: MavenDepedencies]

---

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at str.A.abc(A.java:17)
at str.OurLogic.main(OurLogic.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2889)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1602)
at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.supports(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:54)
at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:46)
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:270)
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:177)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:214)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:63)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyHandler(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:725)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.isWritableProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:557)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 28 more
```

Answer (score 0):

A assume is problem with Spring version 4 and Hibernate version 5.

Check this post [Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739022/caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-lorg-hibernate-engine-filterdefiniti)

Answer (score 0):

I used the Hibernate-core 3.6 final jar to solve the above problem.