# when run the project shows Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to read properties from a properties file in Spring Framework I amusing SpringToolSuite MVC template my code as follows

here is my project directory structure
I am using the java platform JDK 1.8
spring framework 4.0.1
jstl 1.2.1
i am give the details of the project below.
I am getting
when run the project spring MVC hibernate shows error .

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: sample.dao.studentDao sample.controller.studentController.stDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory sample.dao.studentDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
```

this is dispatcher-servelt.xml program

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    
    -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="sample"></context:component-scan>
     <mvc:annotation-driven/>
     
   
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
<!--    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />-->
          
          
          
          
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatemvc"/>
<property name="username" value="root"/>
<property name="password" value="mysql"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="sample"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

this code is studentcontroller.java file

```
package sample.controller;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import sample.dao.studentDao;
import sample.entity.Details;


/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */

@Controller
public class studentController {
      @Autowired
    studentDao stDao;
     @RequestMapping(value ="index.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index()
    {
        System.out.println("at index");
        return "index";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value ="insert.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String insert
        (
            @RequestParam("id") Integer id,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("fee") String fee,
              @RequestParam("sname") String sname,
              @RequestParam("contactno") String contactno
        )
  
        {

        Details ei= new Details();
        ei.setName(name);
        ei.setEmail(email);
        ei.setFee(fee);
        ei.setSname(sname);
        ei.setContactno(contactno);
        
        stDao.save(ei);
        
        Gson ob = new Gson();
        return "success";
   }
    
 @RequestMapping(value="fetch.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String display() 
    {
        List<Details> listdetails = (List<Details>) stDao.display();
        return new Gson().toJson(listdetails);
    }

    
    @RequestMapping(value = "delete.htm")
    public @ResponseBody  String delete(@RequestParam("id") Integer id)
    {
        stDao.delete(id);
        return "successful";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "edit.htm")
    public @ResponseBody  String edit(@RequestParam("id") Integer id)
    {
        List editlist;
        editlist = stDao.getDetailsForEdit(id);
        return new Gson().toJson(editlist);
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "update.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String update
        (
            @RequestParam(value="id",required=false) Integer id,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("fee") String fee,
            @RequestParam("sname") String sname,
            @RequestParam("contactno") String contactno
       )
        {
            
        Details st = new Details();
        st.setName(name);
        st.setEmail(email);
        st.setFee(fee);
        st.setSname(sname);
        st.setContactno(contactno);
        System.out.println("st");
        stDao.update(st);
        Gson ob = new Gson();
        return "success";
    }

}
```

this is studentDao.java file

```
package sample.dao;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projections;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import sample.entity.Details;


/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
@Transactional
@Repository
public class studentDao {

   @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public void save(Details stdinfo) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(stdinfo);
        session.close();
    }
public List display() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Details.class);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
                .add(Projections.property("name"), "name")
                .add(Projections.property("email"), "email")
                .add(Projections.property("fee"), "fee") 
                .add(Projections.property("sname"), "sname") 
                .add(Projections.property("contactno"), "contactno"));
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        List list = criteria.list();
        session.close();
        return list;
    }

    
     public void delete(Integer id){
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction trx = session.beginTransaction();
        Details stdtl = new Details(id);
        session.delete(stdtl);
        trx.commit();
        session.close();
    }
  
     
     
     public List getDetailsForEdit(Integer id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Details.class);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
                .add(Projections.property("name"), "name")
                .add(Projections.property("email"), "email")
                       .add(Projections.property("fee"), "fee")
                       .add(Projections.property("sname"), "sname")
                .add(Projections.property("contactno"), "contactno")
        );
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        List list = criteria.list();
        session.close();
        return list;
    }

    public void update(Details Stdinfo){
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction trx = session.beginTransaction();
        
        session.update(Stdinfo);
        trx.commit();
        session.close();
    }      
}
```

this is web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  metadata-complete="true">
    
     <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
    
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36739956/7132739) helps. However, it seems to be a dependency problem.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition` seems pretty clear on what is wrong.

Comment: ok thank you .now i changed hibernate versions that problem solved.